# Amazon Price Tracker and Push notification

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

as my 2nd python project I am trying to build this amazon price tracker (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY) with 3 lines of extra code for a desktop push notification (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KshTf2A5aUk) instead of an email. When I run the code I don't get an error but neither do I get a push notification. Do you have a any idea?

My code is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import win10toast

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/WOTR-Elektro-Skateboard-Off-Road-vierr%C3%A4drige-Elektroroller-Fernbedienung/dp/B07ZX6TV79/ref=sr_1_25?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=e+skateboard&qid=1597239289&sr=8-25'

headers = {"User Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[0:4])

    if(converted_price > 700):
        send_alert()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

def send_alert():
        toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier().show_toast("Python", 'Cheaper', duration=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **`check_price()`** function in order to run you code and also **`converted_price = float(price[0:4])`** this piece of code will give you an error, you should be doing this with **`split()`** so it will be precise as **`price[0:3]`** will work for **100-999** but if it's **999+** it will convert the wrong price.

Below is the revised code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import win10toast
import time

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/WOTR-Elektro-Skateboard-Off-Road-vierr%C3%A4drige-Elektroroller-Fernbedienung/dp/B07ZX6TV79/ref=sr_1_25?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=e+skateboard&qid=1597239289&sr=8-25'

headers = {"User Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price.split(",")[0])
    print(converted_price)

    if(converted_price > 700):
        send_alert()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

def send_alert():
        toaster = win10toast.ToastNotifier().show_toast("Python", 'Cheaper', duration=5)

while True:
    check_price()
    time.sleep(5) #sleep 5 seconds before requesting the price again
```

Comment: Thanks man but I ran your code and it doesn't work either

Comment: it gives me a traceback error in line 31 and an attribute error "Traceback (most recent call last): File "Neup.py", line 31, in <module> check_price() File "Neup.py", line 15, in check_price title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"